# ASPHTTPResquest in IOS - Response status Code as Zero

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

I am trying to access one of my URL in my code. It returns the StatusCode as zero.

What is this? could not understand..

Code : calling method

```
{
ASIHTTPRequest* request = [[MUGatewayHelper sharedGatewayHelper] prepareRequestForURL:requestURL];               
request.delegate = self;                                                                                            
request.didFinishSelector = _didFinishSelector;                                                                     
request.didFailSelector = _didFailSelector;
}
```

My response(status Message) is 'null' with statuscode of 'zero'

Please guide me. I have tried with some other URL in my code. It works perfectly. I am sure, My Connection code is correct. is there any certification issue in ios device? But If I connect the same URL thorugh ios device safari, i can get the response . Is there any blocking in ASIHttpRequest ? or probelm with server?

Please Guide me. I am totally confunsed,...

Edit on : Feb 11

I have got some invalid SSL certificate exception in the error. But my SSL certificate is original. If the add the cookies value in Firefox, it works. But if add the cookies in ASIHttpRequest , still i am getting the responderstatus is 0. any idea?

Edit on FEb 11 at 9.30

Hi Friends, I have used the GET request in safari,chorme and firefox . it works fine. When I am using the same URL in iphone browser, it returns the 404 exception. incase i am using in the ASIHTtpRequest in the Code, I am getting the exception code status zero. is it specific reason ?  Please guide me... I am stuck up much .. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post the function in which you are calling the URL, post response as well.

Comment: I have added the code what i have used in my coding

Comment: try to open the url in web browser whether it is working or, not. Or you open terminal and type curl <url>..

Comment: I have tried with REST-client in firefox.. it did not work. But When I have tried with safari or IE. It returns the response.   It GET type request.

Comment: ASIHTTP is no longer under development, you should use the AFNetworking library or an alternative maintained one instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the functions to use `ASIHttpRequest` are present in documentation. your code does not look as per document requirement.
Read the 
[documention of ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use). It will help. 
`requestFinished` is a delegate method which is invoked when URL returns the response.

Comment: Here, I have used some call back mechanisham.. It works fine for one of my request...  If i have connected the my client machine, it returns the status code zero..

Comment: I have tried with REST-client in firefox.. it did not work. But When I have tried with safari or IE. It returns the response. It GET type request

Comment: check this, person getting same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263504/asihttprequest-send-a-weired-status-code-of-zero-not-reaching-the-server

Comment: Thanks AsifHabib. I have got some invalid SSL certificate exception in the error. But my SSL certificate is original. If the add the cookies value in Firefox, it works. But if add the cookies in ASIHttpRequest , still i am getting the responderstatus is 0. any idea?

Comment: Check out the Handling redirection, Cookies, in the Documentation,

Comment: Hi I have tried to set the cookies in the request. But still it I am getting the status code value as zero. is there any specifice reason ? NSDictionary *properties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"ARPT", NSHTTPCookieName, @"POQRWNS10.50.4.170CKKWW", NSHTTPCookieValue,      @"aaa.ts.net", NSHTTPCookieDomain,  @"/", NSHTTPCookiePath,[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60*60],NSHTTPCookieExpires,nil]; NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [[[NSHTTPCookie alloc]initWithProperties:properties]autorelease];
[aRequest setRequestCookies:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:cookie]];